# MariaDB Inner join is slow

Tags: performance, mariadb, sql-execution-plan

Here is my SQL (with explain):

```
EXPLAIN
UPDATE
    VF_KRED kred
INNER JOIN GBI gbi ON
    kred.vendor = gbi.vendor
INNER JOIN MASTER_DATA master_data ON
    master_data.vendor_code = gbi.vendor 
SET
kred.GBI_VAL_REP =
(CASE
    WHEN kred.country = 'JP' THEN
    CASE
        WHEN gbi.WITHHOLD_TAX_CODE = 0 THEN 2
        WHEN gbi.WITHHOLD_TAX_CODE = 'IN' THEN 1
    END
    ELSE
    CASE
        WHEN gbi.WITHHOLD_TAX_CODE = master_data.REDUCED_RATE THEN
        CASE
            WHEN gbi.WITHHOLD_TAX_CODE = 0 THEN 3
            WHEN gbi.WITHHOLD_TAX_CODE BETWEEN 1 AND 19 THEN 4
        END
        ELSE 5
    END
END);
```

Giving below the outcome:

[image]

Now, the `UPDATE` SQL takes ~6+ minutes.

Below are the indexes on tables:

- VF_KRED table:

[image]

- GBI table:

[image]

- MASTER_DATA table:

[image]

`VENDOR` columns are all `varchar(25)` type.

**-- EDIT:** (describing whole table structure below):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE GBI;

CREATE TABLE `GBI` (
  `VENDOR` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `COMPANY_CODE` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VENDOR_NAME` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `WITHHOLD_TAX_TYPE` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `WITHHOLD_TAX_CODE` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DOCUMENT_CURRENCY` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CREATE_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VENDOR`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE VF_KRED;

CREATE TABLE `VF_KRED` (
  `VENDOR` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `COUNTRY_CODE` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEARCH_TERM` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `GBI_VAL_REP` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 5,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VENDOR`),
  KEY `vf_kred` (`GBI_VAL_REP`),
  KEY `VF_KRED_COUNTRY_IDX` (`COUNTRY`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `vf_kred_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`GBI_VAL_REP`) REFERENCES `VENDOR_RATE_CATEGORY` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE MASTER_DATA;

CREATE TABLE `MASTER_DATA` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VENDOR_CODE` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `VENDOR_NAME` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `APPLN_RECEIVED_FROM_US` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITUNES_CONTRACT_NUM` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTRACT_EXPIRATION_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTO_RENEWAL` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `REDUCED_RATE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORM_17` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `RESIDENCY_CERT_ISSUE_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAX_AUTHORITY_SUBMISSION_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAX_AUTHORITY_ACCEPTANCE_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORM_17_EXPIRATION` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENTS` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `REMARKS` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CATEGORY` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `MASTER_DATA_VENDOR_CODE_IDX` (`VENDOR_CODE`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2369 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Any clues?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  They will expose one problem.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  That may be another problem.

Comment: @RickJames Pls see updated question. innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 134217728; RAM = 8GB

Comment: There is no good way to make a `SELECT *` with no `WHERE` clause faster. The database will have to do full table scans on both tables because you requested *all* records and *all* columns. The potential to make this query faster comes from making it more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. My pain point was actually an Update SQL. I had just specified Select equivalent here to make it easy. Changing my question to show actual Update SQL now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix `CHARACTER SETs` (or datatypes or collations) on columns that need to be compared, as in a `JOIN`.  Note how `vendor` is `latin1` versus `utf8`.  This slows down the `JOIN`.  (Also, check `vendor_code` due to another join.)

The clue in `EXPLAIN`:  "func".  This implied that somehow `vendor` was being modified in order to perform the `JOIN`.   The `CREATE TABLE` showed that the charset was different.

128MB for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is find, even advisable, if you have only 1GB of RAM.  For 8GB, `6G` would be a better setting.  By increasing the value, you will probably cut back on the I/O necessary to run this, and other, queries.  Again, this impacts the speed of the `JOIN`.